# how to make cursor move backward/forward in QT?

Tags: qt, cursor

I am with an input method project by QT on meego.

here is a case: if user input "(" in inputing widgets, a ")" should displayed too. you know, at that moment, cursor is in the position after ")", but it should be between brackets.

what should I do ? with QT

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: If you're using `QLineEdit`, there are cursor methods (cursorBackward, cursorForward, cursorPosition, etc.) http://developer.meego.com/api/1.2/qt4/qlineedit.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the right way:

```
QEvent *movePress= new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_Left,   Qt::NoModifier);
QApplication::sendEvent (focusWidget, movePress);

QEvent *moveRelease= new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease,  Qt::Key_Left,  Qt::NoModifier);
QApplication::sendEvent(focusWidget,moveRelease);
```